# Java mocks - dynamically replace class with mock object

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking

I'd like all instances of a class to be replaced with a mock at run time. Is this possible? For example, in a test, I would like to mark `class Bar` as a mocked class. In test scope, inside `class Foo`'s constructor, `new Bar()` should return a mocked instance of `Bar`, not the real class.

```
class Bar {
    public int GiveMe5() {
        return 5;
    }
}

public class Foo {
    private Bar bar;

    Foo() {
        bar = new Bar();
    }
}
```

Then in my test:

```
class TestFoo {
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        // Tell the mocking framework every instance of Bar should be replaced with a mocked instance
    }
    @Test
    private void testFoo() {
        Foo foo = new Foo(); // Foo.bar should reference a mocked instance of Bar()
    }
}
```

Comment: This type of thing is usually accomplished via dependency injection.

Comment: What about a `setBar(Bar bar)` method. This would be the most easy solution, yet you can also set it via reflection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try PowerMockito and whenNew method. You should be able to return a mock instance when constructor of Foo class is invoked.

Answer (score 1):

You could do complex things with mocking newed instances in Mockito, but it's much, much more straightforward to simply inject the dependency you need under test.

```
public class Foo {

    private Bar bar;

    Foo(Bar bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }
}
```

At that point you can inject *whatever* instance of `Bar` you want into this class, including mocks.

Comment: The code above is oversimplified. In reality, I'll have to propagate this dependency injection and change my production code just so that I can run my test. PowerMockito whenNew is basically what I want to do

Comment: This approach would not work if `Bar` is a real object, that is, if it has instance state initialized in a constructor (`new Bar(1, "data")`, for example). Such objects cannot be injected through DI.

Comment: @Rogério:  The *point* is to move away from that pattern entirely when injecting `Bar`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a mocking library which supports the mocking of "newed" (future) objects. Both JMockit and PowerMock support it. With JMockit, for example, a test would look like:

```
public class FooTest {
    @Test
    public void mockAllInstancesOfAClass(@Mocked Bar anyBar) {
        new Expectations() {{ anyBar.giveMe5(); result = 123; }};

        Foo foo = new Foo();
        // call method in foo which uses Bar objects

        // asserts and/or verifications
    }
}
```